# How can I view the code that Scala uses to automatically generate the apply function for case classes?

Tags: scala, macros, case-class, scala-compiler

When defining a Scala case class, an apply function is automatically generated which behaves similarly to the way the default constructor in java behaves. How can I see the code which automatically generates the apply function? I presume the code is a macro in the Scala compiler somewhere but I'm not sure.

To clarify I am not interested in viewing the resultant apply method of a given case class but interested in the macro/code which generates the apply method.

Comment: I would guess it's not a macro, since macros were added to Scala long after case classes.

Comment: It is not a macro, it is just the compiler functionality. Why do you want to see that code?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm just curious thats all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a macro. Methods are synthesized by compiler "manually".

`apply`, `unapply`, `copy` are generated in `scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers`

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Namers.scala#L1839-L1862

```
/** Given a case class
 *   case class C[Ts] (ps: Us)
 *  Add the following methods to toScope:
 *  1. if case class is not abstract, add
 *   <synthetic> <case> def apply[Ts](ps: Us): C[Ts] = new C[Ts](ps)
 *  2. add a method
 *   <synthetic> <case> def unapply[Ts](x: C[Ts]) = <ret-val>
 *  where <ret-val> is the caseClassUnapplyReturnValue of class C (see UnApplies.scala)
 *
 * @param cdef is the class definition of the case class
 * @param namer is the namer of the module class (the comp. obj)
 */
def addApplyUnapply(cdef: ClassDef, namer: Namer): Unit = {
  if (!cdef.symbol.hasAbstractFlag)
    namer.enterSyntheticSym(caseModuleApplyMeth(cdef))

  val primaryConstructorArity = treeInfo.firstConstructorArgs(cdef.impl.body).size
  if (primaryConstructorArity <= MaxTupleArity)
    namer.enterSyntheticSym(caseModuleUnapplyMeth(cdef))
}

def addCopyMethod(cdef: ClassDef, namer: Namer): Unit = {
  caseClassCopyMeth(cdef) foreach namer.enterSyntheticSym
}
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Namers.scala#L1195-L1219

```
private def templateSig(templ: Template): Type = {
  //...

  // add apply and unapply methods to companion objects of case classes,
  // unless they exist already; here, "clazz" is the module class
  if (clazz.isModuleClass) {
    clazz.attachments.get[ClassForCaseCompanionAttachment] foreach { cma =>
      val cdef = cma.caseClass
      assert(cdef.mods.isCase, "expected case class: "+ cdef)
      addApplyUnapply(cdef, templateNamer)
    }
  }

  // add the copy method to case classes; this needs to be done here, not in SyntheticMethods, because
  // the namer phase must traverse this copy method to create default getters for its parameters.
  // here, clazz is the ClassSymbol of the case class (not the module). (!clazz.hasModuleFlag) excludes
  // the moduleClass symbol of the companion object when the companion is a "case object".
  if (clazz.isCaseClass && !clazz.hasModuleFlag) {
    val modClass = companionSymbolOf(clazz, context).moduleClass
    modClass.attachments.get[ClassForCaseCompanionAttachment] foreach { cma =>
      val cdef = cma.caseClass
      def hasCopy = (decls containsName nme.copy) || parents.exists(_.member(nme.copy).exists)

      // scala/bug#5956 needs (cdef.symbol == clazz): there can be multiple class symbols with the same name
      if (cdef.symbol == clazz && !hasCopy)
        addCopyMethod(cdef, templateNamer)
    }
  }
```

`equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` are generated in `scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SyntheticMethods`

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/SyntheticMethods.scala

```
/** Synthetic method implementations for case classes and case objects.
 *
 *  Added to all case classes/objects:
 *    def productArity: Int
 *    def productElement(n: Int): Any
 *    def productPrefix: String
 *    def productIterator: Iterator[Any]
 *
 *  Selectively added to case classes/objects, unless a non-default
 *  implementation already exists:
 *    def equals(other: Any): Boolean
 *    def hashCode(): Int
 *    def canEqual(other: Any): Boolean
 *    def toString(): String
 *
 *  Special handling:
 *    protected def writeReplace(): AnyRef
 */
trait SyntheticMethods extends ast.TreeDSL {
//...
```

Symbols for accessors are created in `scala.reflect.internal.Symbols`

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Symbols.scala#L2103-L2128

```
/** For a case class, the symbols of the accessor methods, one for each
 *  argument in the first parameter list of the primary constructor.
 *  The empty list for all other classes.
 *
 * This list will be sorted to correspond to the declaration order
 * in the constructor parameter
 */
final def caseFieldAccessors: List[Symbol] = {
  // We can't rely on the ordering of the case field accessors within decls --
  // handling of non-public parameters seems to change the order (see scala/bug#7035.)
  //
  // Luckily, the constrParamAccessors are still sorted properly, so sort the field-accessors using them
  // (need to undo name-mangling, including the sneaky trailing whitespace)
  //
  // The slightly more principled approach of using the paramss of the
  // primary constructor leads to cycles in, for example, pos/t5084.scala.
  val primaryNames = constrParamAccessors map (_.name.dropLocal)
  def nameStartsWithOrigDollar(name: Name, prefix: Name) =
    name.startsWith(prefix) && name.length > prefix.length + 1 && name.charAt(prefix.length) == '$'
  caseFieldAccessorsUnsorted.sortBy { acc =>
    primaryNames indexWhere { orig =>
      (acc.name == orig) || nameStartsWithOrigDollar(acc.name, orig)
    }
  }
}
private final def caseFieldAccessorsUnsorted: List[Symbol] = info.decls.toList.filter(_.isCaseAccessorMethod)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I could point out few points in the codebase that might be relevant.

First, there is a way to correlate *Scala Language Specification* grammar directly to source code. For example, [case classes](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes) rule

```
TmplDef  ::=  ‘case’ ‘class’ ClassDef
```

relates to [`Parser.tmplDef`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/bb894b2f925fbc698845a92d84b4ba260bfcb733/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Parsers.scala#L2887)

```
    /** {{{
     *  TmplDef ::= [case] class ClassDef
     *            |  [case] object ObjectDef
     *            |  [override] trait TraitDef
     *  }}}
     */
    def tmplDef(pos: Offset, mods: Modifiers): Tree = {
      ...
      in.token match {
        ...
        case CASECLASS =>
          classDef(pos, (mods | Flags.CASE) withPosition (Flags.CASE, tokenRange(in.prev /*scanner skips on 'case' to 'class', thus take prev*/)))
        ...
      }
    }
```

Specification continues

> A case class definition of `[tps](ps1)…(ps)` with type parameters
>   tps and value parameters ps implies the definition of a companion
>   object, which serves as an extractor object.
>
> ```
> object  {   
>   def apply[tps](ps1)…(ps): [tps] = new [Ts](xs1)…(xs)   
>   def unapply[tps](: [tps]) =
>     if (x eq null) scala.None
>     else scala.Some(.xs11,…,.xs1) 
> }
> ```

so let us try to hunt for *implied definition* of

```
def apply[tps](ps1)…(ps): [tps] = new [Ts](xs1)…(xs)
```

which is another way of saying synthesised definition. Promisingly, there exists [`MethodSynthesis.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/ecf9899e97ed3299712b317e25b0ae9264bd08f9/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/MethodSynthesis.scala)

```
/** Logic related to method synthesis which involves cooperation between
 *  Namer and Typer.
 */
trait MethodSynthesis {
```

Thus we find two more potential clues `Namer` and `Typer`. I wonder what is in there? But first `MethodSynthesis.scala` has only approx 300 LOC, so let us just skim through a bit. We stumble accross a [promising line](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/ecf9899e97ed3299712b317e25b0ae9264bd08f9/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/MethodSynthesis.scala#L238)

```
val methDef = factoryMeth(classDef.mods & (AccessFlags | FINAL) | METHOD | IMPLICIT | SYNTHETIC, classDef.name.toTermName, classDef)
```

"`factoryMeth`"... there is a ring to it. Find usages! We are quickly led to

```
  /** The apply method corresponding to a case class
   */
  def caseModuleApplyMeth(cdef: ClassDef): DefDef = {
    val inheritedMods = constrMods(cdef)
    val mods =
      if (applyShouldInheritAccess(inheritedMods))
        (caseMods | (inheritedMods.flags & PRIVATE)).copy(privateWithin = inheritedMods.privateWithin)
      else
        caseMods
    factoryMeth(mods, nme.apply, cdef)
  }
```

It seems we are on the right track. We also note the [name](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/ecf9899e97ed3299712b317e25b0ae9264bd08f9/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/StdNames.scala#L687)

```
nme.apply
```

which is

```
val apply: NameType                = nameType("apply")
```

Eagerly, we find usages of `caseModuleApplyMeth` and we are wormholed to [`Namer.addApplyUnapply`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/ecf9899e97ed3299712b317e25b0ae9264bd08f9/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Namers.scala#L1851)

```
    /** Given a case class
     *   case class C[Ts] (ps: Us)
     *  Add the following methods to toScope:
     *  1. if case class is not abstract, add
     *   <synthetic> <case> def apply[Ts](ps: Us): C[Ts] = new C[Ts](ps)
     *  2. add a method
     *   <synthetic> <case> def unapply[Ts](x: C[Ts]) = <ret-val>
     *  where <ret-val> is the caseClassUnapplyReturnValue of class C (see UnApplies.scala)
     *
     * @param cdef is the class definition of the case class
     * @param namer is the namer of the module class (the comp. obj)
     */
    def addApplyUnapply(cdef: ClassDef, namer: Namer): Unit = {
      if (!cdef.symbol.hasAbstractFlag)
        namer.enterSyntheticSym(caseModuleApplyMeth(cdef))

      val primaryConstructorArity = treeInfo.firstConstructorArgs(cdef.impl.body).size
      if (primaryConstructorArity <= MaxTupleArity)
        namer.enterSyntheticSym(caseModuleUnapplyMeth(cdef))
    }
```

Woohoo! The documentation states

```
<synthetic> <case> def apply[Ts](ps: Us): C[Ts] = new C[Ts](ps)
```

which seems eerily similar to SLS version

```
def apply[tps](ps1)…(ps): [tps] = new [Ts](xs1)…(xs)
```

Our stumbling-in-the-dark seems to have led us to a discovery.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that, while others have posted the pieces of code that generate the *name* of the method, the *signature*, the *type*, the corresponding symbols in the symbol table, and pretty much everything else, so far nobody has posted the piece of code that generates the *actual body* of the case class companion object `apply` method.

That code is in [`scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Unapplies.factoryMeth(mods: Global.Modifiers, name: Global.TermName, cdef: Global.ClassDef): Global.DefDef`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Unapplies.html#factoryMeth(mods:Unapplies.this.global.Modifiers,name:Unapplies.this.global.TermName,cdef:Unapplies.this.global.ClassDef):Unapplies.this.global.DefDef) which is defined in [`src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Unapplies.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Unapplies.scala#L143-L144), and the relevant part is this:

> ```scala
> atPos(cdef.pos.focus)(
>  DefDef(mods, name, tparams, cparamss, classtpe,
>    New(classtpe, mmap(cparamss)(gen.paramToArg)))
> )
> ```

which uses the [`TreeDSL`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/TreeDSL.html) internal Domain Specific Language for generating Syntax Nodes in the Abstract Syntax Tree, and (roughly) means this:

- At the current position in the tree (`atPos(cdef.pos.focus)`)
- Splice in a method definition node (`DefDef`)
- Whose body is just a `New` node, i.e. a constructor invocation.

The description of the `TreeDSL` trait states:

> The goal is that the code generating code should look a lot like the code it generates.

And I think that is true, and makes the code easy to read even if you are not familiar with the compiler internals.

Compare the generat*ing* code once again with the generat*ed* code:

> ```scala
> DefDef(mods, name, tparams, cparamss, classtpe,
>  New(classtpe, mmap(cparamss)(gen.paramToArg)))
> ```

```scala
def apply[Tparams](constructorParams): CaseClassType =
  new CaseClassType(constructorParams)
```