# Scala case class method: `public scala.collection.Iterator<java.lang.String> productElementNames()`

Tags: scala, case-class, scalac

if we have a look into the bytecode produced by this case class compilation

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

we get besides others this method:

```
public scala.collection.Iterator<java.lang.String> productElementNames();
```

So, the question is, where it comes from and why it can not be called on a Person's instance like, for instance the other one from the same compiled class

```
public scala.collection.Iterator<java.lang.Object> productIterator();
```

I use this versions:

```
$ scala -version                                                                                                                                                                                              
Scala code runner version 2.13.8 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

$ scalac -version                                                                                                                                                                                             
Scala compiler version 2.13.8 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

[idea screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39KTi.png)

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Product.scala

Comment: *"why it can not be called on a Person's instance like..."* Why did you decide that it can't be called?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999247/how-can-i-view-the-code-that-scala-uses-to-automatically-generate-the-apply-func/

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/GcOc9Oz2SlmN2SoGUIApig/1

Comment: it definitely can be called, what makes you think it cannot?

Answer (score 1):

Solved

thanks to @DmytroMitin and @ElectronWill

Yes, `productElementNames()` is a method inherited from the `Product`.

It is definitely callable in Scala 2.13.8, with which the sample is compiled.

The problem was, that the IDE thought it was Scala 2.12.4, where the `Product` did not yet contain that method.

Comment: You can always check whether your code compiles with `sbt clean compile`. Don't rely completely on what your IDE says.